# Dynamically adding onscroll function

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a set of tabbed tables. tabs are added during runtime, and each tab has 4 tables with data associated with the tab.

I also have a requirement that each table scrolls data but the header remains visible and consistent with the scroll.

I have seen examples of this and implemented it just fine, well for the first tab.

Since the ids need to be unique, I use the Angular Js ng-attr-id to generate unique ids.

My problem now is how to reference the unique ids when creating the onscroll function.

With a single tab, I can use this code:

```
<table id="Orders" onscroll="$('#Orders > *').width($('#Orders').width() + $('#Orders').scrollLeft());">
```

This works absolutely fantastic, now using Angular's ng-attr-d, I don't know how to set the function since it needs to be dynamically created using the dynamic id:

```
<table ng-attr-id="Orders{{GroupDetails.length}}" onscroll="$('#Orders{{GroupDetails.length}} > *').width($('#Orders{{GroupDetails.length}}').width() + $('#Orders{{GroupDetails.length}}').scrollLeft());">
```

This above does not work. Inspection shows that the {{}} parts are rendered as string.

Is there an Angular JS way to 'inject' event functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue with syntax, you can add a variable to string and assign it to `ng-attr-id`.
Try this:

```
<div ng-attr-id="{{ 'orders-' + GroupDetails.length }}"></div>
```

Comment: ng-attr-id is not the issue. My problem is how to reference the id when adding the onscroll event.